# Why is "setter is defined without getter" a JSHint error?

Tags: javascript, jshint, lint

Reference [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3R9U/)

```
var obj = {
  set bla(k) {
    console.log(k);
  }
};
```

JSHint flags this as "setter is defined without getter". I am sure there is a way to turn this off, but why is this an error at all? Everything I have seen JSHint flag has had a reasonable explanation. I can't come up with a reason for why this is a bad thing.

Comment: I would consider this a design flaw. Setters that only care about side effects (console.log in your case) are unconventional, and if they actually change the instance you'd expect that you can read the new value somehow. Make it a method.

Comment: This is actually more common in perl, the write-only language.

Comment: You can disable it like so: set: foo { } // jshint -W078

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think JSHint has a good reason to warn about this situation. I don't see anything in the specification (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm, pages 30-31) that requires there to be a getter if there is a setter or vice versa, and it is easy to imagine a setter that doesn't imply a getter. For example, you might want to set a dirty flag in a setter. There would be no reason to define a getter.

I did not see a justification in the JSHint source, or its history.

Comment: I agree, there are plenty of use cases for a setter affecting the *behavior* or a *calculation* etc. on an object with no reason to ever `getFoo()` on it.  If getters and setters are always paired you have reduced an object to a procedural language `struct`.

Comment: It's not mistaken, since it doesn't *flag* it as a `Syntax Error`, but merely *warns* that "a setter is defined without getter"

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely flagged because it's suspicious. Write-only properties are a fairly unusual thing. The odds that you're doing it on purpose are much lower than the odds that you made a mistake. This is similar to warning when you write `foo == null` — it isn't illegal or even *necessarily* wrong, but it's more likely to be wrong than right.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have code like this and you'll get the same JSHint error:

```
appSession: {
    officername: "Denis Test",
    get getOfficername() {
        return `${this.officername}`;
    },
    set setOfficername(name) {
        this.officername = name;
    }
};
```

However, if the getter and setter have the same name as below and the prefixes `get` and `set` are before them the error will go away:

```
    get Officername() {
        return `${this.officername}`;
    },
    set Officername(name) {
        this.officername = name;
    }
```

Notice the difference in how I named my methods in the two examples. For your case, add a `get` method of the same name as your 'set' method and your error will go away.

```
var obj = {
    set bla(k) {
        console.log(k);
    }
    get bla(){
        console.log(obj.bla);
    }
};
```